# Error: Cannot determine GraphQL input type when passing array as input type in typegraphql

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I'm using TypeGraphQL and TypeORM. In my input types, I have a field that looks like this:

```js
@Field(() => [String], { nullable: true })
  options: string[];
```

However. I keep getting this error,

```
Error: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for options
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/search?q=string+array&type=

Comment: Please update to `1.0.0` RC version which has more descriptive error messages

Answer (score 0):

Syntax seems to be fine, can you give us a little more info? Are you just using TypeORM+TypeGraphQL with something like Express or do you use NestJS? How are you importing `Field`?

Comment: This should rather be a comment instead of an answer

Comment: Yeah sorry, I've never been very active on this site and I thought I might give it a try. I wanted to post a comment, but it said I needed a reputation of at least 50 for that. Should I remove this?

Comment: It ended up being an entirely unrelated issue in another file which also had an options array